# can we get image name from SKSpriteNode?

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, xcode5.0.1

We can assign image in SKSpriteNode using the code

```
SKSpriteNode *currentSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[_arrayImg objectAtIndex:1]];
```

But how can I get the image name from the SKSpriteNode **currentSprite**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could also do this:

```
SKSpriteNode* currentSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[_arrayImg objectAtIndex:1]];
[currentSprite setName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [_arrayImg objectAtIndex:1]]];
```

then finding the SKSpriteNode do,

```
SKSpriteNode* currentSprite = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [_arrayImg objectAtIndex:1]]]
```

or finding out the image name of the SKSpriteNode do,

```
for (SKNode* node in self.children) {
    if ([node isKindOfClass:SKSpriteNode.class]) {
        SKSpriteNode* sprite = (SKSpriteNode*)node;
        NSString* name = sprite.name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to "remember" it, for example in userData.

```
NSString* imageName = [_arrayImg objectAtIndex:1];
SKSpriteNode *currentSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:imageName];
currentSprite.userData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:imageName 
                                                            forKey:@"imageName"];
```

Comment: Actually the array image is not the array of images at first I wrote the question wrong. The array images are array of SKTexture. So how can i get the image name.

Comment: Store the textures in a dictionary with keys being the image name.